# SQL table not created when deploying a WAR file to Liferay

Tags: sql, liferay, portlet

I've created a JSR-268 portlet for Liferay which uses services to interact with a database. I can deploy the portlet without problems or errors, but the table defined by the services is not created!

I get no "table not found" error when I test the portlet. I get no errors at all! The table just isn't there in the database. I've found other things on the internet saying that I should use the generated "create.sql" file that the Liferay Service Builder created, but I don't see that file anywhere.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 12):

Have the tables never been created? I had a similar problem when I deleted the tables by hand. I thought they would be created again when deploying the portlet again, but it didn't happen.

After studying the source code I found out that Liferay stores information about the portlets in the table `servicecomponent` and checks 2 things before it executes the (pseudo) SQL in `META-INF/tables.sql`:

1. The `build.number` in `service.properties` must be higher than that, stored in `servicecomponent`,
2. The `tables.sql` must be different from the one stored in `servicecomponent`.

Only then the `tables.sql` is executed.

An easy way to achieve that, is to delete all entries in `servicecomponent` addressing your portlet.

Comment: You have also to delete it from the table RELEASE_ and then redeploy it.

Answer (score 3):

Try by deleting an entry from servicecomponent table. And redeploy your portlet.

```
delete FROM servicecomponent where buildNamespace="<your table namespace>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem and below given solution **works for me.**

**Steps**

1. I have changed the **build.number** in **service.properties** higher than that stored in servicecomponent.
2. Removed all the xml files from **META-INF** folder.
3. Removed all the sql files from **webapp/WEB-INF/sql** folder.

Then **build-service** and **deploy** will creates custom tables that are defiend in **service.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using serviceBuilder in Liferay 6.2 when you define a new entity in the Liferay schema in service.xml, the first time that any Portlet tries to access the table it will be created if it's not exist.

There are several problems when you're using a different schema because sometimes Liferay not create tables automatically. Then you need to lauch the Creation SQL sentence and create it manually and then access it through LocalServiceUtil.